# Changing the line type on a density plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability-density, density-plot

I am trying to change the line type of a density curve, just so that it stands out relative to the rest of the density curves that I have on the same plot. However, the issue is that when I use the "linetype" function to make a dashed curve (i.e. linetype=2), there is no error, but the actual line type remains only solid. This is what I tried:

```
Globalpdf<-ggplot() 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[1:5,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation45), 
color="black", size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[16:20,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation45), 
color="black", size=3, linetype= 2) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[29:33,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocation45), color="blue",size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[1:5,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocation85), color="black", size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[16:20,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocation85), color="black", size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[29:33,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocation85), color="red", size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[1:5,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocationco), color="green", size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[16:20,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocationco), color="green", size=3) 
+ geom_density(data=GEV[29:33,], mapping = 
aes(x=GLocationco), color="green", size=3) 
+ xlab("One-day max (mm/day)") + ggtitle("Global") 
+ xlim(150, 300)+theme(plot.title = element_text(size=54))+ 
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=54)) 
+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=54)) 
+ theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

Doing this correctly produces the series of pdf curves on the plot, as shown below, but the second black curve that I specified to appear as "dashed" remains as a solid black curve, rather than the desired dashed black curve. It is only that one that I require to appear as dashed. Is there a reason why it is not working?

[image: Sample density plot]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Not an answer to the question you asked, but if you tidied your data, your code would be: shorter, more robust, easier to understand, shorter ... and many other "good to have" features...

Comment: I think it has to do with your data, not your plotting code, as I do get a dashed line by creating fake data with `GEV <- data.frame(GLocation45 = rnorm(20), GLocation85 = rnorm(20), GLocationco = rnorm(20))`

Comment: I agree with @Alexlok. Not reproducible.

Comment: Hi guys - I just found the issue. There was nothing wrong with the data - it was just that there was overlap with those black curves (i.e. two curves using the same color). So, the plot output was giving the illusion that there was no dashed black curve - it was hidden. Thus, I just removed the duplicate black curve. Also, I placed the function "linetype" after "size=3" where appropriate, and it worked just fine!

Comment: Thanks for all of your advice, though!!

Answer (score 1):

- I strongly recommend you start a new line after each `+`, so that the syntax can be more readable;
- I think `linetype = 2` can be put inside `aes()`.

Comment: Once moving linetype = 2 into the aes(), exactly as you showed there (without the asterisks), but I instead received this error: Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to linetype
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, then I'd say that I agree with the comments above, I suggest looking into how you preprocessed the data.

Comment: I just found the issue. There was nothing wrong with the data - it was just that there was overlap with those black curves (i.e. two curves using the same color). So, the plot output was giving the illusion that there was no dashed black curve - it was hidden. Thus, I just removed the duplicate black curve. Also, I placed the function "linetype" after "size=3" where appropriate, and it worked just fine! Thanks for your advice, though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the linetype into the aes() like this.... (obvs remove the 2 pairs of Asterix)

```
Globalpdf <- ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[1:5,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation45), color="black", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[16:20,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation45, **linetype=2**), color="black", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[29:33,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation45), color="blue",size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[1:5,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation85), color="black", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[16:20,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation85), color="black", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[29:33,], mapping = aes(x=GLocation85), color="red", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[1:5,], mapping = aes(x=GLocationco), color="green", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[16:20,], mapping = aes(x=GLocationco), color="green", size=3) + 
  geom_density(data=GEV[29:33,], mapping = aes(x=GLocationco), color="green", size=3) + xlab("One-day max (mm/day)") + 
  ggtitle("Global") + xlim(150, 300)+theme(plot.title = element_text(size=54))+ 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=54)) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=54)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: I tried moving it into the aes(), exactly as you showed there (without the asterisks), but I instead received this error: Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to linetype
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just found the issue. There was nothing wrong with the data - it was just that there was overlap with those black curves (i.e. two curves using the same color). So, the plot output was giving the illusion that there was no dashed black curve - it was hidden. Thus, I just removed the duplicate black curve. Also, I placed the function "linetype" after "size=3" where appropriate, and it worked just fine!